# Mimic Azure App Service authorization locally in ASP.NET core app

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am using in-built authentication of Azure App service to authorize access to my ASP.NET core app - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization . Is there a way to mimic what Azure App service does in my machine so that I can run the same integration test on my local endpoint and cloud endpoint.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Without Azure App service , you can use ASP.NET Core OpenID Connect middleware to integrate Azure AD into an ASP.NET Core web app :

Code samples :

[Integrating Azure AD into an ASP.NET Core web app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54546245/5751404